# Add SOAP header with xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML and an XSL, I manage to do the transformation of the body but now I need to add some headers.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://www.adonix.com/WSS">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <wss:run soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <callContext xsi:type="wss:CAdxCallContext">
        <codeLang xsi:type="xsd:string">ENG</codeLang>
        <poolAlias xsi:type="xsd:string">satest4</poolAlias>
        <poolId xsi:type="xsd:string">?</poolId>
        <requestConfig xsi:type="xsd:string">?</requestConfig>
     </callContext>
     <publicName xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST</publicName>
     <inputXml xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[
  // here is the body 

     ]]>
     </inputXml>
  </wss:run>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I achieve that? The header I want to add that starts before the body and ends after ?

Comment: I see you have a CDATA block in your template. If you are generating the XML properly, it is usually not necessary to use CDATA. If the client complains that they *NEED* it, then it is usually a sign that they are not reading the XML properly with XML tools, but just doing some string parsing and hacky garbage. If that is the case, then rather than facilitate that, you should push back and tell them to do it right.

Comment: To add to that, the element is called `inputXml` but the type is `xs:string`  I usually see that because people find JAXB bindings are more simple if they just make everything a string and then parse that serialized XML, instead of dealing with how to properly handle `xsd:any`.

Comment: I dont understand your last message :) But the message I get is Input XML flow should be a string. Maybe you forgot to add CDATA tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that content in the template matching the root node, and put `xsl:apply-templates` inside the `inputXml` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:wss="http://www.adonix.com/WSS">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <wss:run soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                    <callContext xsi:type="wss:CAdxCallContext">
                        <codeLang xsi:type="xsd:string">ENG</codeLang>
                        <poolAlias xsi:type="xsd:string">satest4</poolAlias>
                        <poolId xsi:type="xsd:string">?</poolId>
                        <requestConfig xsi:type="xsd:string">?</requestConfig>
                    </callContext>
                    <publicName xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST</publicName>
                    <inputXml xsi:type="xsd:string">
                        
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
          
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                        
                    </inputXml>
                </wss:run>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>  
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, works in 1.0.  I'l update the version in that example.

Comment: Input XML flow should be a string. Maybe you forgot to add CDATA tag, thats the message I get

Comment: So, if you need the XML serialized as a string you can apply the normal transforms and wrap with CDATA blocks fairly easily (updated).